# How does the content of lib end up in a Android *.apk file?

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, aapt

Android App apk-files are actually zips. Using ([JNI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/jniTOC.html)), i.e. native code means to add *.so files to your apk. My question is how do they actually end up inside of the apk file?

I know so far that, looking at the [example](http://developer.android.com/ndk/samples/sample_hellojni.html) how such `*.so` are build and used from within the Java-code. What I do already know is how such files are eventually stored like this inside of the apk/zip archive:

```
res/
assets/
META-INF/
lib/
  |<arch1>
        |libSharedNativeLib1.so
        |libSharedNativeLib2.so
  |<arch2>
        |libSharedNativeLib1.so
        |libSharedNativeLib2.so
AndroidManifest.xml
classes.dex
resources.arsc
```

I know also how the entries `classes.dex`,`AndroidManifest.xml`,`resources.arsc`,`assets`,`res` and `META-INFO` are made. It is a succession of [`aapt`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/tools/aapt/), `jarsigner`. The only thing I have no idea is now the `lib` is put into the apk.

## Background

I like to keep things simple. Using IDE such as `Android Studio` and `Eclipse` seems a nice way to shurtcut here, since they keep the users somewhat in the dark to what happens `automagically` in the background of the actual building process (being done with the help of various build-tools such as ANT, Maven, Grandle, Groovy...)

While there is nothing really bad about such tools, they tend to reduce the knowledge needed to pull of the trick of "building a apk", and consequently seem to reduce the documetation about a manual way to achieve the very same thing. It would help me much to know what Grandle actually does when the zip files end up in the apk/zip archive.

Right now I have tested and this seems to work

```
zip -r appfile.apk lib
```

and testing it seemed that upon installing the Android system actually really copied and linked into place the correct lib*.so native app's namely
to

```
root@armdev:/data/data/name.package # ls -l
total 12
drwxr-x--x    2 10142  10142  4.0K .
drwxrwx--x  103 1000   1000   8.0K ..
lrwxrwxrwx    1 1012   1012   42 lib -> /data/app/name.package/lib/arm
```

Now one could assume that Androids `pm install appfile.apk` simply goes by looking for the lib folder structure inside of the `apk/zip` file and copies the lib*so files in place and symlinks them to `/data/data/name.package/lib`, but I would really like to know if there is more to it, not as to depend on being only lucky with the `zip` command above.

I have already tried `aapt`'s `-A` (for assets) and `-S` (for resources) but neither worked to include the lib folder into the apk file via `aapt`.

, will end up packed into the  apk-file within a folder lib//lib*.so

I want to develop some Android software ( *.apk file / an App ) and I do not use IDEs like Android Studio or Eclipse and neither Building Tools as Grandle, Maven, nor Ant....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **zip** is quite safe (until some breaking change is introduced in a future version of Android). You could work with **aapt**, but it does not accept the nice *recursive* flag. You can have a look at the system [code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/jni/com_android_internal_content_NativeLibraryHelper.cpp) that extracts the shared libraries. There is no magic, it opens the contents table of the ZIP (a.k.a. APK) file, and looks for files that match the supported ABI.

Comment: thank you, just one thing about this "breaking change", is this something the Android Developers are known to do, i.e. make breaking changes, or are they more "Microsoftish" and break while keeping change, i.e. care about backwards compatibility?

Comment: The nature of mobile OS is such that backwards compatibility is essential. Not all devices can be upgraded, and on the other hand old apps are expected to run after OTA upgrade. But it's not that breaking changes in corner cases never happened before; and this could happen on some isolated fork, like Amazon's, or on a semi-fork (i.e. heavily customized AOSP), like Samsung's. The open-source does often help here, bugs are easier to track, and sometimes it's easier to find a workaround. Specifically regarding the native libraries installation I personally encountered a couple of corner-case bugs